# Could not successfully Import class in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I created a two class named **Vendor** and **Address** in one file called business.groovy(that is I created package using the name **business**)
And in the same folder I created another groovy code that imports the business package and make use of Vendor class attributes(Vendor is class in business package). But when I try to create a object for Vendor in that groovy script, it throwing error stating that:

> /home/Anto/Groovy/pakg/Imports.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class Vendor 
>    @ line 2, column 13.
>      def canoo = new Vendor()

What do I have to do? Where did I go wrong?

These are the files I created:
**business.groovy**

```
package business
class Vendor {
public String name
public String product
public Address address = new Address()
}
class Address {
public String street, town, state
public int zip
}
```

**impotTesting.groovy**

```
import business.*
def canoo = new Vendor()
canoo.name = 'Canoo Engineering AG'
canoo.product = 'UltraLightClient (ULC)'
```

And when I try to execute the **importTesting.groovy** file by using **groovy importTesting** command, I get the error as I mentioned before!

Comment: What do you use to compile and run groovy scripts? Some IDE or build tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to either use some build tool like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), or IDE like [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html) to control your classpath/compilation/runtime needs.

EDIT: It should be like that:

```
baseDir/business/business.groovy
baseDir/impotTesting.groovy
```

Your compiled classes should also resemble the same directory structure:

```
baseDir/business/business*.class  
baseDir/impotTesting*.class
```

Then your baseDir should be added to the CLASSPATH.

Comment: then you need to modify your CLASSPATH variable to include the folder where compiled Groovy files are.

Comment: ya my groovy Files are getting compiled and running using the commands(groovyc and groovy) but the problem is in packages :(

Comment: do you define the package in the start of Groovy file?

Comment: do your Groovy files reside in some folder structure? what is the value of your CLASSPATH variable?

Comment: ya i do :! and one more question for the pakage definition file, i have to use what extension? Whether it is needed to compile that too, before using it anywhere in Import statements?

Comment: package is just a keyword in the begining of the source file. Like in Java e.g. package org.myorg.vendor;

Comment: Ya my groovy files reside in the same folder structure

Comment: I think you need to extend your question with more details about the scripts (the most intresting part is the header with imports) that you have and the folder structure that you have.

Comment: Oh ok fine sir :) will do that

Comment: then your business.groovy should be located in "business" folder

Comment: ya fine, i have now moved the file business.groovy to business folder, where should i keep importTesting.groovy file then?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create Vendor.groovy and Address.groovy containing the respective class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced similar issue while learning Groovy.
In order to run your example from command line using `groovy` command (tested with Groovy 2.4.12), you should:

1. Follow directory structure of your src files as @Andrey Adamovich suggested. So, both your `.groovy` files should reside in `business` folder
2. Open `cmd`, navigate to the parent of `business` folder, e.g. `src/main/groovy` for my projeсt (I have structure `src/main/groovy/business`).
3. Execute the script with command `groovy business/importTesting.groovy`