# Import error in jar file in Groovy

Tags: java, csv, groovy, jar

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220965/could-not-successfuly-import-class-in-groovy) I have a small groovy test script that basically uses the example from [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) java library:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("GroovyTest.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
    }
```

I keep getting the error "unable to resolve class au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader".  I even put the opencsv jar file in the same directory as my script but it does not recognize it.  I assumed this was a classpath issue so I tried with -cp tag only to receive the same error.

I am running from the command line as `$ groovy testg.groovy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy won't automatically pick up jars from the current working directory.  You can either call groovy with a classpath (`-cp <classpath>`), or put the jar file `${user.home}/.groovy/lib`.

Your example worked for me when I launched it like this:

```
groovy -cp opencsv-2.2/deploy/opencsv-2.2.jar testg.groovy
```

Comment: alternatively use the @Grab annotation.

Comment: Looks like I was not being explicit enough and assuming that the jar being in the same directory would be good enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*
```

The import is working fine for me